# Can't release the variable ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

my method is

```
-(void)readAppFile
{
    NSString *plistPath = [self getDataFileDestinationPath];
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    if (!temp) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
    }
    items = [[temp objectForKey:@"Items"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"temp %lu", (unsigned long)[temp retainCount]);
    [temp release];
}
```

When I added the `[temp release];` - but something is wrong and my method is crashed. Can't understand what's wrong.. As I can see from memory leaks instrument - I need to release this variable.. Any help?

Comment: can you post the error message you are getting? or maybe a crash log?

Comment: Please read this: [When to use -retainCount?](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist nice link, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];` method returns autoreleased object. 
and autorelease pool send the release message once more time.

check out this link, to know how to use autorelease pools https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you should be releasing `items` instead of releasing `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

This retured an **autoreleased** id which you typecasted into NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

And then you released it once more by `[temp release];`